# Does ubuntu-20.04 autoinstall atomatically boot from USB?

Tags: boot, server, usb, preseed

I am trying to setup a new system, but I do not have a GPU nor integrated graphics as I plan to just use the machine as a server. I ordered a SATA to usb adapter so I can just install ubuntu using a different machine, but I was wondering if after performing these steps:

1. Create user-data (auto install file)
2. Created the iso using ubuntu-autoinstall-generator
3. Made the iso bootable using isohybrid
4. Used Rufus to format the usb with the iso. (not sure if this does the same as step 3)
5. plug in to machine and wait.

p.s: I am using a windows 10 machine with a kali linux WSL shell to perform the steps above

should the machine automatically boot from the usb drive?
Since I have no display I could try to guess using a keyboard, but is it possible to make it boot from the usb automatically when turned on? I tried loading the iso in virtual box and it does exactly what I want and sets up openssh for me and I am able to ssh into the virtual box machine, but I am pretty sure nothing is happening on my server machine, as I am unable to find the ssh connection even after 30 minutes of waiting. I am trying to install **ubuntu-20.04**.

Here are links to the programs I used (corresponding to the steps above):

2. ubuntu-autoinstall-generator:
   https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-autoinstall-generator
3. rufus:
   https://rufus.ie/en/

Here are some references I used:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apb.html

- I think this is the old autoinstall? I could not find anything really on preseeding for ubuntu 20.04, but rather found the autoinstall stuff which seems to be basically the same.

2. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart

- This was my main reference I used as well as some other threads from the community

3. https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Make-Ubuntu-Autoinstall-ISO-with-Cloud-init-2213/#Step0)PrerequisitesandCreatingthe\

- Referenced step 0 in this article

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: @David Sorry I just added the version to the question